# Revealing Module Pattern, KnockoutJS, and CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This may be very beginner question, or maybe I am using too many things at once.  I am trying to use KnockoutJS with the [Revealing Module Pattern](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code-revealing-module-pattern) and trying to write CoffeeScript. I have put my model in a separate function. Here is the code:

```
myapp =(->
    person =->
        firstname = ko.observable "k"
        lastname = ko.observable "d"

        firstname:firstname,
        lastname:lastname

    person : person
)()

$(->
    ko.applyBindings(new myapp.person())
    @
)
```

Now this is creating JavaScript using workbench in Visual Studio like this:

```
(function() {
  var myapp;

  myapp = (function() {
    var person;
    person = function() {
      var firstname, lastname;
      firstname = ko.observable("k");
      lastname = ko.observable("d");
      return {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname
      };
    };
    return {
      person: person
    };
  })();

  $(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new myapp.person());
    return this;
  });

}).call(this);
```

Now this is giving error that it could now found element to bound. Here is the simple HTML text:

```
<p>
    Firstname<span data-bind="text: myapp.person().firstname"></span>
    Lastname<span data-bind="text: myapp.person().lastname">
    </span>
</p>
```

If I create normal JavaScript without self called function it working fine. Here is the function:

```
myapp = (function () {
    var person;
    person = function () {
        var firstname, lastname;
        firstname = ko.observable("k");
        lastname = ko.observable("j");

        return {
        firstname : firstname,
        lastname : lastname
        }
    }

    return {
        person: person
    }
})();


$(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new myapp.person());
})
```

Can anyone explain what is going wrong here? Or is there another way to write CoffeeScript to use KnockoutJS?

Please comment if further details are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/Kqa2k/

```
myapp = (->
    person =->
        firstname = ko.observable "jack"
        lastname = ko.observable "sparrow"

        firstname:firstname,
        lastname:lastname

    person : person
)()

$(->
    ko.applyBindings(new myapp.person())
    @
)
```

​  You need to change bind syntax :

```
<p>
    Firstname: <span data-bind="text:firstname"></span>
    Lastname: <span data-bind="text:lastname">
    </span>
</p>​
```

Because when you call ko.applyBindings(new myapp.person()) you set your view for only a person object not all myapp object.

If you want to set your view for whole myapp you need to change your code like this :

[JSfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/6etHW/)

```
myapp = (->
    person = (fname,lname)->
        firstname = ko.observable fname
        lastname = ko.observable lname

        firstname:firstname,
        lastname:lastname

    person : new person("Jack" , "Sparrow")    

)()

$(->
    ko.applyBindings(myapp)    
    @
)

<p>
    Firstname: <span data-bind="text:person.firstname"></span>
    Lastname: <span data-bind="text:person.lastname">
    </span>
</p>​
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks. One more request, can you please explain it where I am doing wrong or how binding works. So, I will take care next time.

Thanks again.

Comment: Its simple when you call ko.appyBindings(x) you define a model(x) for your view. It means that you can only access x properties from data-bind. You created a single person Object when you call new myapp.person(). Which means that you can only acess firstname and lastname fields. But you used myapp.person().firstname to reach person's name. There is no myapp and person object exist in your model. I set my model to myapp which has a newly created person object. So i can access first the person object then its field from data-bind like  person.firstname